# Redirect homepage to authenticated page Laravel 8 Jetstream Livewire [Solved]

Tags: laravel, authentication, redirect, laravel-jetstream

I have the home page in web.php the login page:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
 return view('auth.login');
});
```

And when the user logs in the authenticated page:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/admin', function () {
 return view('admin.index');
})->name('panel');
```

The problem is that if I manually type in the url of the browser, the main page appears the login page when it should redirect to the authenticated page since the user does not have to re-enter the credentials.

In RouteServiceProvider.php:

```
public const HOME = '/admin';
```

*****EDIT*****___

I have followed these steps to be able to fix it:

1- We create the controller:
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function redirectUser()
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return view('admin.index');
        } else {
            return view('auth.login');
        }
    }

}
```

2- In web.php:

```
Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\\HomeController@redirectUser')->name('homeController');
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum', 'verified']], function () {
    Route::get('/admin', function () {
        return view('admin.index');
    });
});
```

3- In RouteServiceProvider.php:

```
public const HOME = '/admin';
```

With this, what I do is that every time someone enters the main page if they are not logged in, go to the login page and if they are logged in, go to the / admin page, but also if on the admin page I put the full url it redirects to the admin.

Answer (score 0):

After appplied https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum configuration,
like in app/Http/Kernel.php, in api array group, you must add  `\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,` at top of the array group
Use `Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens` trait in User class Model.

And finally add this line in your .env config
`SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS='localhost:8000'`

Here you can update `localhost:8000` with the domain you are accessing the site.

Comment: Thanks Dyos, I have modify my code and edited my previous post, now it's work.